# Public Function Not Working Unless in Formula

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I have a Public Function called "Get_Months" which I am attempting to use in a Sub.  I have managed to get things to work when it is placed in a formula as below:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("CO2:CO" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[10]=""DUMMY"",Get_Months(RC[-80],RC[-79] + 1),""ERROR"")"
```

I am trying to avoid having formulas placed onto the sheet however, so I was attempting something like this:

```
 Dim LastRow As Long
 LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 Set SelectionRNG = Range("M2:N" & LastRow)
 For Each rngRow In SelectionRNG.Rows
 rngRows.Cells(1, 80) = Get_Months(rngRows.Cells(1, 1), rngRows.Cells(1, 2) + 1)
```

The syntax (as I understand it) for the public function is "Get_Months(Date1,Date2).

Any tips anyone can give will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: one is called `Get_Months` the other is `Get_Months_Between`?

Comment: @ScottCraner Sorry that was a typo - they are named and typed exactly the same in my VBA Module

Comment: I think you're looking for [evalute](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/evaluate.htm)

Comment: Your For Each control variable is rngRow, so you should be referring to rngRow, not rngRows, in your last line of code.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using DateDiff?

Comment: @Jeeped yes unfortunately we need a different (less common) method for how we round dates in this situation and as far as my research showed, you cannot adjust within the datediff function itself

Comment: @Domenic Good catch !  It looks like that has it fixed -- I'll do some more testing but I think that solved it.  Feel free to post a solution.

Comment: @Sgdva  I read through the link you posted, but not sure exactly how it would have been used in this situation.

Comment: can you add the definition of Get_Months, or at least it's parameter and return types. Evaluate can be used, but it's a bit overkill

Comment: If you don't want the values and you already have the formula defined, set evaluate and get the value from it instead of typing it on the WB

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the formulas to values like this:

```
With Range("CN2:CN" & LastRow)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[10]=""DUMMY"",Get_Months(RC[-80],RC[-79] + 1),""ERROR"")"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: A better solution than looping, but I liked to avoid the extra steps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't loop.

```
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Range("CN2:CN" & LastRow)
   .Value = Get_Months(.Cells(1, -80), .Cells(1, -79) + 1)
End With
```

Comment: The code you provided works - but only for row 2.  I checked in the immediate box and LastRow = 70.  I also verified that there are dates in every row of column M & N. Any idea why it would not be filling all rows ?

Comment: I didn't think it all the way through, but have edited/corrected my answer.  *A note:* as a rule you should avoid looping.  It's slow/expensive.

Comment: looping by using an index also fails if you have zero objects, unless you specifically check for the zero condition ... _For Each_ does not have that issue